# Prevent rounding of datetime column in Google graphs X axis

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a working google chart that shows data for the last 24 hours, one data set for each hour (ex 01:00 to 01:59...etc). Now I am trying to modify it to make it show data for the last 24 hours but in 60 minutes chuncks starting from the current time (ex 17:20 to 18:19... etc). This is the code I am working on (https://jsfiddle.net/70boo2ss/):

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Hours');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Col 1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Col 2');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Percentage');

    data.addRows([
        [new Date(1454963244*1000),329,35,10.64],
        [new Date(1454959644*1000),17,1,5.88],
        [new Date(1454956044*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454952444*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454948844*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454945244*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454941644*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454938044*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454934444*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454930844*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454927244*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454923644*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454920044*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454916444*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454912844*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454909244*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454905644*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454902044*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454898444*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454894844*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454891244*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454887644*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454884044*1000),60,24,40.00],
        [new Date(1454880444*1000),60,24,40.00],
    ]);

    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
            fractionDigits: 2,
            suffix: '%'
    });
    formatter.format(data, 3);

    var options = {
        width: 1600,
        height: 500,
        backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1',
        colors: ['#ff851b', '#03a9f4', '#8dc859'],
        chartArea: {top:50, left:50, width: 1500},
        hAxis: {format: 'h:mma', textStyle: { fontSize: '12' }, gridlines: { count: 24 }},
        vAxes:[
            { },
            {   gridlines: { color: 'transparent' }, minValue: 0, maxValue: 100, format: '#\'%\'', viewWindowMode : 'explicit', viewWindow:{
                max:100,
                min:0
        }}],
        series:[
            {targetAxisIndex:0},
            {targetAxisIndex:0},
            {targetAxisIndex:1}
        ]
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

As you can see on jsfiddle, the graphical data gets offset to the correct datetime chunks of 60mins, but the horizontal axis starts at :00

How do I make the horizontal axis start the same as the graphical representation instead of :00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your own `ticks` and `viewWindow: {min: lowest_date_in_data}` for the hAxis.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 data.addColumn('datetime', 'Hours');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Col 1');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Col 2');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Percentage');

 data.addRows([
  [new Date(1454963244*1000),329,35,10.64],
  [new Date(1454959644*1000),17,1,5.88],
  [new Date(1454956044*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454952444*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454948844*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454945244*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454941644*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454938044*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454934444*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454930844*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454927244*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454923644*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454920044*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454916444*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454912844*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454909244*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454905644*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454902044*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454898444*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454894844*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454891244*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454887644*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454884044*1000),60,24,40.00],
  [new Date(1454880444*1000),60,24,40.00],
 ]);

    // build ticks
    var ticks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      ticks.push(data.getValue(i, 0));
    }

 var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
   fractionDigits: 2,
   suffix: '%'
 });
 formatter.format(data, 3);

 var options = {
  width: 1600,
  height: 500,
  backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1',
  colors: ['#ff851b', '#03a9f4', '#8dc859'],
  chartArea: {top:50, left:50, width: 1500},
  hAxis: {
          format: 'h:mma',
          textStyle: { fontSize: '12' },
          gridlines: { count: 24 },
          ticks: ticks,  // set ticks
          // set min window
          viewWindow: {min: data.getValue(data.getNumberOfRows() - 1, 0)}},
  vAxes:[
   { },
   { gridlines: { color: 'transparent' }, minValue: 0, maxValue: 100, format: '#\'%\'', viewWindowMode : 'explicit', viewWindow:{
    max:100,
    min:0
  }}],
  series:[
   {targetAxisIndex:0},
   {targetAxisIndex:0},
   {targetAxisIndex:1}
  ]
 };

 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

 chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```